# How to access to specific cells in vtkPolyData?

Tags: vtk

Question : Is there a way to have direct access to a specific cell in vtkPolyData structure?

I'm using vtkPolyData to store sets of lines, say L.
Currently, I'm using GetLines() to know the number of lines in L. Then, I have to use GetNextCell to go through this set of lines using a "while" loop.

Current code is something like:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> a;
...
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> lines = a->GetLines(); 
...
while(lines->GetNextCell(numberOfPoints, pointIds) != 0)
```

-> I'd like to be able to work directly on a specific line by doing something like:

```
myline = a[10];
doSomething(myline);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could get an access to a specific cell using [vtkDataSet::GetCell(vtkIdType     cellId)](http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.10/html/classvtkDataSet.html#a711ed1ebb7bdf4a4e2ed6896081cd1b2) function